# Method to re-open a connection on a datacontext if it has gone down

Tags: c#

The following method is used to keep a `DataContext` open if it is closed or broken and is called before most calls to access the database.

It runs in a service that needs constant access to the database, constantly opening and closing the connection would be too costly. So we only reconnect if the connection has been closed, i.e. we have been kicked off.

```
private void OpenConnection<T>(System.Data.Linq.DataContext dataContext, string connectionString) where T : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    try
    {
        if (dataContext != null && dataContext.Connection != null)
        {
            if (dataContext.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed
             || dataContext.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken)
            {
                dataContext.Dispose();
                dataContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        if (dataContext != null)
        {
            dataContext.Dispose();
        }
        dataContext = null;
    }

    if (dataContext == null)
    {
        dataContext = (T)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), connectionString);
    }
}
```

It is called like:

```
OpenConnection<MyDataContext>(instanceOfMyDataContext, connectionString);
```

My main concerns are if my use of generics is correct and if the `as T` on creating an instance of the `DataContext` is correct. Although all pointers about my code are welcomed.

Comment: If you create an instance of base class then cast will always fail. Use Activator.CreateInstance() instead

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I copied this from an old version of the method not realising that line was still in there, as no one as answered yet I have updated the question to show the use of `Activator`. If this is frowned upon I will revert the edit though

Comment: Another small thing: `dataContext` parameter should be `ref`, like this you're writing a new instance on local variable and caller (then also future calls) won't see the new instance. (I'm not sure but I suppose it's OK to update a question until there isn't an answer)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I feel that's more of a review than a comment if you want to expand it into an answer? Either way thanks

Comment: Too small (IMO) for an answer. I have a question: isn't connection pooling effective in your case? There shouldn't be any serious performance hit with a _normal_ approach (with `using`) until connection is kept in pool and reused for each call (also I think EF caches _something_ on its own to reduce construction overhead if you do not pass a connection string and you read it from .config)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm not sure to be honest, this was mainly a hacky solution to a problem we was having with a customer that needed to go out ASAP. I've since come back to the code and tried to make it a bit more generic and slightly better.

Comment: You may try, pooling is already pretty good. To make it right isn't easy (what about multiple threads?) BTW in this function you may also want to apply a _retry pattern_ to handle transitory errors (for example temporary network connectivity issues or server reboots.) I wrote few posts about this somewhere (not sure if here on CR or SO)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'll have a look into that, either way that will start becoming out of scope for this Q and A :) Thanks again

Comment: I concur with comments.  Why do you even need T if dataContext is System.Data.Linq.DataContext.   If it is null then you just create it without opening it.   Are you sure this is even working code?

Comment: @Paparazzi How else would I create a new instance of the class? I can't use `new DataContext` as `DataContext` is the base class not the class I want to create an instance of...

Comment: Lets just leave as it makes not sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, not sure I fully understand why you're doing this but taking that as a given here are some tips to make your code a bit more readable and concise.

**Namespaces**

Unless you have conflicts with other namespaces, I'd suggest adding `using System.Data;` and `using System.Data.Linq;` to the top of you file. If you do have a conflict and you created it yourself (not from a 3rd-party library) I'd suggest changing the name so there isn't a conflict *if possible*. Just makes things easier.

**Method Extensions**

Those if-statements you've got are kind of ugly. You could create a couple of method extensions for the DataContext class like this.

```
public static class DataContextExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks that the context and its connection are not null.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool HasContextAndConnection(this DataContext dataContext)
    {
        return dataContext != null
            && dataContext.Connection != null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the context's connection is broken or closed.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsConnectionClosedOrBroken(this DataContext dataContext)
    {
        // NOTE: You can add the above null-checks to this one so that this 
        // function doesn't throws a NullReferenceException if called before the other.
        return dataContext.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed
            || dataContext.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken;
    }
}
```

**Try-Catch**

You should be intentional with your code, having a wide-open try/catch states to whoever is reading it "The person who coded this has no idea what could possibly go wrong with it." (or more commonly, "I'm too lazy to list out what could go wrong."). So not only does it make you look bad, but it also doesn't provide any information to the reader/maintainer of what is expected to go wrong.

So then you should look into what could go wrong. Well, we're already doing null-checks so there shouldn't be any `NullReferenceExceptions`. That leaves the `Dispose()` method and the `Activator.CreateInstance` being the only other two possibilities.

According to the [IDisposable.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page, Dispose should never throw an exception. Additional [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35803278/1467644) reference here too. So we should be good there.

`Activator.CreateInstance` however, could throw a handful of exceptions and you don't have a try-catch around that. Here's the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) page that outlines the exceptions that could be thrown.

**Result**

```
private void OpenConnection<T>(DataContext dataContext, string connectionString) 
    where T : DataContext
{
    // DISPOSE: Clean up the existing context if the connection is closed or broken.
    if (dataContext.HasContextAndConnection() && !dataContext.IsConnectionClosedOrBroken())
    {
        dataContext.Dispose();
        dataContext = null;
    }

    // CREATE: Instantiate a new context given the connection string.
    if (dataContext == null)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        try
        {
            dataContext = Activator.CreateInstance(type, connectionString);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException)
        {
            // Constructor threw an exception.
        }
    }
}
```

**Personal Touch**

Personally, I like adding the header comments you see above. Where the all-caps part is a quick 1-2 word description of the section and everything after is a bit more detailed. I find it helps me scim code faster, however that is something that needs maintained when code is changed.

Comment: I'm not happy with the comment part. If you would use proper helper variables then you wouldn't need the comments. The first one could be `canDisposeContext` and the second one `contextExists`. The code would explain itself. Your comments explain what you do but I can already read it looking at the code. You only should and need to explain **why** you are doing something. This cannot usualy be easily discovered.

Comment: A technical paper's paragraphs explain the paper and yet they still have headers as a quick description. I agree that code should explain itself, and your comment should explain why if-not inherently obvious. I just find them as a nice quick skim to find a section of code, especially if you go weeks without touching the code again. Maybe even in an ideal world you wouldn't need such headers, but in my experience the ideal world is just that, an Idea.